# Вызов метода из __construct

Tags: php, ооп

Привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли обращаться к методам класса из магического метода __construct, например таким вот образом:

```
class userModel extends systemClass
{
    /**
     * userModel constructor.
     * @param null $type  - string or int - field to receive data about the user (id, login)
     * @param null $value - string        - the value of which is the data is returned
     */
    public function __construct($type = null, $value = null)
    {
        if ($type == "id") {
            return $this->getById($value);
        } elseif ($type == "login") {
            return $this->getByLogin($value);
        }
    }

    public function getByLogin($login)
    {
        $db = new query();
        $user = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM user where login=?s", $login);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new Exception('User is not found', 404);
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        $db = new query();
        $user = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM user where id=?i",$id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new Exception('User is not found', 404);
        }
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете, но конструктор не вернет данные пользователя!

Comment: @Visman то есть обязательно обращаться напрямую к методу?

Comment: если данные хотите вернуть, то или к методу, или к публичному свойству.

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно можно. Только нужно убрать конструкции return в конструкторе, т.к. из конструктора ничего не возвращается. Я изменил для наглядности ваш пример:

```
<?php

class userModel
{
    public function __construct($type = null, $value = null)
    {
        if ($type == "id") {
            $this->getById($value);
        } elseif ($type == "login") {
            $this->getByLogin($value);
        }
    }

    public function getByLogin($login)
    {
        echo __METHOD__ . " '$login'";
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        echo __METHOD__ . " '$id'";
    }
}

new userModel('id', 'login'); // userModel::getById 'login'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я немного другое хотел спросить. Как мне после объявления объекта: $user = new userModel('id', 1); -- получить массив данных о пользователе: $user['name'];?

Comment: @Di- почему бы после инициализации не вызвать метод возврата юзера?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Лень матушка. :-D Уже почитал про arrayAccess. Спасибо.

Comment: @Di- такой возможности нет. Сперва надо создать экземпляр класса `$user = new userModel(1);` а уже после этого вызывать соответствующий метод _(или свойство класса)_. [демо-пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e66e1f640bd2438dab1bc22ea7239db2ac1a90f)